# Ошибка при записи образа Windows IoT на microSD для Raspberry Pi3

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi

Скачал с официального сайта Microsoft, программу Windows 10 IoT Core Dashboard [отсюда](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=708576)
. 
Это основное меню настроек, сделал скрин на телефон (извиняюсь за качество).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После нажатия "Скачать и установить", в течении достаточно длительного времени идёт установка, в конце выпадает ошибка "Не удалось записать файл подготовки на карту microSD". Если вставить данную флешку в Raspberry Pi3, то на экране будет красоваться ошибка.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У кого-нибудь было что-нибудь похожее? В сети нашёл только, о том, что вроде как флешка не подходит или её нужно отформатировать специальной утилитой SDFormatter. Утилитой пользовался не помогло. Флешка SanDisk Ultra Micro SDHC 16GB, именно её рекомендуют [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/hardwarecompatlist) на официальном сайте Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

В общем разобраться в проблеме не удалось, более того флешка, после того как над ней поработала Win Dashbord Core перестала форматироваться, возможно оно и к лучшему, т.к. получилось её вернуть по гарантии и взять новую, но в этот раз по дороже от Samsung, на неё установка прошла гладко, хотя сообщение, о том что не удалось записать файл подготовки никуда не пропало, но запустилось всё на ура. Надеюсь кому-нибудь будет полезна данная инфа.